# Retrieve calling method and build a call on the fly?

Tags: python, methods, overriding

I have the following code ... and I have several more like this (&,|,^,) the only difference is the method name `__method__` as you can see.

Is there a way to to have a separate method that get as parameter the method name and construct a call , so I have just a redirect call in every "override".

```
   def __add__(self, rhs) :
                assert self.sdp[:LSDP.LVLBITS] == rhs.sdp[:LSDP.LVLBITS], "add: operands must be at the same level"
                return (self.sdp[:LSDP.LVLBITS]).cat( self.sdp[LSDP.LVLBITS:].__add__(rhs.sdp[LSDP.LVLBITS:]) )
        def __mul__(self, rhs) :
                assert self.sdp[:LSDP.LVLBITS] == rhs.sdp[:LSDP.LVLBITS], "mul: operands must be at the same level"
                return (self.sdp[:LSDP.LVLBITS]).cat( self.sdp[LSDP.LVLBITS:].__mul__(rhs.sdp[LSDP.LVLBITS:]) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [operator module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html), have a common method that takes the operation to call and the right hand side

```
def _run_operator(self, op, rhs):
    assert self.sdp[:LSDP.LVLBITS] == rhs.sdp[:LSDP.LVLBITS], f"{op.__name__}: operands must be at the same level"
    return (self.sdp[:LSDP.LVLBITS]).cat(op(self.sdp[LSDP.LVLBITS:], rhs.sdp[LSDP.LVLBITS:]))

def __add__(self, rhs):
    return self._run_operator(operator.add, rhs)

def __mul__(self, rhs):
    return self._run_operator(operator.mul, rhs)
```

Comment: don't invent dunder methods, i.e. `__x__`, just call it `_run_operator`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga prefixing a method with `__` is helpful when you would like to obfuscate the method. The trailing `__` was unnecessary though you're right

Comment: No, absolutely not,  double-underscore name-mangling is *to prevent name collisions in subclasses*. Methods that are not part of the public API should be pre-fixed with a *single* underscore. This is a good solution though, just to be clear.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Just been reading the docs, you are right. Thanks for the information